# Retrieve list items Links

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, client-object-model

When retrieving list items via Javascript, how to get the link or action to click and go to that item link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SP.List.get_defaultEditFormUrl()` gives the Edit Url of the list. An Edit url of the item can be created by appending the ID of the `ListItem`. So at the time of loading the list, request `DefaultEditFormUrl`property of the List like: `ctx.load(List, 'DefaultEditFormUrl');`. And at the time of loading the `listitems`, request the `ID` property also like `ctx.load(ListItems,'Include(ID)')`. Finally, the link may be created like this:

```
var href = List.get_defaultEditFormUrl() + "?ID=" + ListItem.get_item('ID');
```

Comment: the same for DefaultDisplayFormUrl ?

Comment: Yes, it works the same way.